# How to clean up photo scans 3d model meshes in 3Ds Max in batch (Bulk Cleaning 100s of models)?

Tags: 3ds-max

[image]I am creating 3d models using photos. Now I want to clean the meshes in 100s of models. Like I have to clean the wall tile scanned model mesh, removing the unwanted part. I want to know is there any method available through which i can clean the 100s of model made using photos taken at same angle. Basically batch cleaning of meshes is possible in 3ds max or not? Attached is the image , similarly we will have lot of meshes made from photos taken at same angle